# Filter Pandas dataframe into excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have an excel spreadsheet with following columns:

[image: Dataframe]

I want to group this data by vendor and show all transaction and amount data for that vendor by Type (i.e. Wireless, Bonus etc). For ex: it should show all data for vendor 'A' classified by 'Type'. Once done, it should export this to separate excel files (i.e. for vendor 'A', 3 excel file are created showing all transactions for different revenue types i.e. Wireless, Bonus and Gift). I tried using pandas Groupby function, but it requires aggregation, which doesn't help solve the problem.

Can anyone provide any guidance/ inputs on how to solve this ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  . What have you tried thus far? Instead of screenshots, copy paste the data so others can use it. Lastly, also add the desired result

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following steps: Use Distinct to get the unique combinations of Vendor and Type. Once you have these unique combinations, loop through them, filter your dataframe and export the filtered dataframe to an Excel sheet.

Comment: Thanks Tarik, I tried that too, but I how do I filter the dataframe by vendor type ? I got the unique values for both vendor and type, but am unable to filter this dataset. Can you help with the code ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please post your code